# Number theory: square numbers of a given form

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I made a proof in an undergraduate number theory class which uses this assumption to make a crucial step in the proof. Could someone tell me if it is correct and maybe explain why or why not?

If I have a square number $2^m(r2^m+s)+1=r2^{2m}+s2^m+1$, where $r,s>0$ and $m, r, s \in\Bbb{N}$ does this imply that the square root of this number must be $n2^m+1$, where $n\in\Bbb{N}$ is such that $n^2=r$ and $2n=s$? The important thing is to show that $s$ is even.

Comment: $13^2=10\cdot2^4+2\cdot2^2+1$ so $m=2,r=10,s=2$ and we note that $10$ is not a square, so no, it's not true.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not; consider the case where $m=1$, $r=5$, $s=2$. Then
$$2^m(r2^m+s)+1=2^1\times(5\times2^1+2)+1=25=5^2,$$
but $r$ is not a perfect square, so such an $n$ does not exist.

Moreover, it does not even imply that $s$ is even, as the values $m=3$, $r=s=5$ give
$$2^3\times(5\times2^3+5)+1=361=19^2,$$
which is a perfect square. There are many examples, the values $m=3$, $r=2$, $s=5$ give
$$2^3\times(2\times2^3+5)+1=169=13^2,$$
in some sense a 'smaller' example. And $m=3$, $r=1$, $s=7$ gives the smallest counterexample;
$$2^3\times(1\times2^3+7)+1=121=11^2.$$

Comment: I thought there might be an issue there, but I couldn't figure it out myself. Thank you for your answer! Glad I checked here.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please accept my answer so that the question doesn't remain open.